# Amazon AWS SDK PHP 2 - Filter tags by instance?

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags

I have been able to retrieve a full list of tags from all my EC2 instances using the PHP SDK but I'm struggling to filter the results down to a particular instance...

```
    // Collect instance information
    $sInstanceId = file_get_contents('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id'); // 'i-52da5b1f'
    $sAvailabilityZone = file_get_contents('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone'); // 'eu-west-1b'
    $sRegion = preg_replace('/^(.*)([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z]{1})/', '$1$2', $sAvailabilityZone);

    use Aws\Common\Aws;
    use Aws\Ec2\Command\DescribeTags;
    use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;

    // Set up the global AWS factory
    $oAWS = Aws::factory(array(
            'key'    => CONST_AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            'secret' => CONST_AWS_SECRET_KEY,
            'region' => $sRegion
    ));

    // Query EC2 for tags
    $oEC2Client = $oAWS->get('ec2');
    $oModel = $oEC2Client->describeTags()->toArray();
```

I've tried changing the call to describeTags to...

```
    $oModel = $oEC2Client->describeTags(array(
            "Filters" => array(
                    array("Name" => "resource-id", "Value" => $sInstanceId)
            )
    ))->toArray();
```

But that seems to make no difference.
Could someone shed some light on this for me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [API docs for Ec2Client.describeTags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_describeTags) show that `Value` should actually be `Values` and should be an array. Try the following:

```
$oModel = $oEC2Client->describeTags(array(
    "Filters" => array(
        array("Name" => "resource-id", "Values" => array($sInstanceId))
    )
))->toArray();
```